# Why is [object Object] viewed in column when trying to bind columns in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, combobox, asp.net-ajax, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is the JS I call in Index on document ready

```
jsonfields = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ColumnData));
```

This is the Ajax Call which I Make to bind

```
function onTeamTreeLoad(e) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.ApplicationPath + 'Generic/GetTeamTree',
            dataType: "json",
            headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": $("#AntiForgeryToken").val() },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    $("#TeamName").kendoDropDownTree({
                        dataSource: {
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    children: "Items"
                                }
                            },
                            data: data
                        },
                        dataTextField:  "Text",
                        dataValueField: "Id"
                    });

                    try {
                        if (e.model.TeamName !== "") {
                            $("#TeamName").data("kendoDropDownTree").text(e.model.TeamName);
                        }
                    } catch (e) { }
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Failed to load');
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Why am I seeing [objectObject] when trying to bind the column? I want the data to be viewed instead of objectObject. I tried adding SerializeObject method to ID and Text but then I could not view that column when editing! I would like to know if there is any mistake in the AJAX call and what are the things that need to be added if using SerializeObject or JSON.Stringify.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are just printing object. So Object -> Stringify give output like [object Object].

You can try this code.

```
for(var prop in obj) {
  console.log(obj[prop]);
}
```